# Customize what log4j2 JSonLayout loggs

Tags: jackson, log4j2

It seems as though in log4j2 when I add  to my appender that what gets logged is a static set of values.  How can I customize what gets logged?

Answer (score 1):

More research led to the answer to my question.  Setting the properties flag to true in the JsonLayout config causes each log message to contain the contents of whatever is in the context map.  So to answer my question, populate the context map with MDC puts and set the properties flag to true and you get your custom content in the log message.

Also, there is a propertiesAsList flag that when set to true also prints out the contents of the context map but does does in key=, value = format.